# select value unset after click button

Tags: vue.js

select with options are generated dynamically. 
When button 'GO' were click select options generates again with different data. But the issue is when user select option 1 and click 'go' automatically option 1 is selected from next select, how to clear that?

my code:

```
<select v-model="key" @change="onChange($event)">
    <option v-for="(option, index) in passSelect"  :value="index" v-if="option!==null" :data-foo="option" @click="onChange($event)" @click="onClick($value)">
       {{ option }}
     </option>
 </select> 
 <button @click="onChildClick" class="button">Go -></button>
```

methods:

```
    onChildClick() {
        this.counter++;
        this.loadAgain();
    },
    getSelect(){
        this.passSelect = this.checkExist();
    },
    onChange(event) {
        this.selectedIndex =  event.target.value;
        this.selectedValue =  event.target.options[event.target.value].dataset.foo;
    },
    loadAgain(){
        this.getSelect();
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Selection is determined by the `v-model`, which is using the property `key`. As you're using the `index` for the `value` this will cause the option with the same `index` as the previous list to be selected.

You need to clear the value of `key` to reset the `<select>`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data () {
    return {
      counter: 0,
      key: null,
      passSelect: [],
      selectedIndex: null,
      selectedValue: null
    }
  },
  
  created () {
    this.getSelect();
  },

  methods: {
    onChildClick () {
      this.counter++;
      this.loadAgain();
    },
    getSelect () {
      this.key = null;
      this.selectedIndex = null;
      this.selectedValue = null;
      this.passSelect = getOptionsList();
    },
    onChange (event) {
      const value = event.target.value;
      
      if (value) {
        this.selectedIndex = event.target.value;
        this.selectedValue = event.target.options[event.target.value].dataset.foo;  
      }
    },
    loadAgain () {
      this.getSelect();
    }
  }
})

function getOptionsList () {
  return ['Red', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Brown', 'Blue', 'Pink', 'Black'].filter(c => {
    return Math.random() > 0.4;
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="key" @change="onChange($event)">
    <option v-for="(option, index) in passSelect"  :value="index" v-if="option !== null" :data-foo="option">
      {{ option }}
    </option>
  </select> 
  <button @click="onChildClick" class="button">Go -></button>
  <p>counter: {{ JSON.stringify(counter) }}</p>
  <p>key: {{ JSON.stringify(key) }}</p>
  <p>selectedIndex: {{ JSON.stringify(selectedIndex) }}</p>
  <p>selectedValue: {{ JSON.stringify(selectedValue) }}</p>
</div>
```

I've also cleared `selectedIndex` and `selectedValue` to try to keep the data consistent.

Some other notes:

1. I've got rid of the 2 `click` listeners on the `<option>`. Not really sure what they were for but you shouldn't have had 2 listeners for the same event on the same element.
2. `key` and `selectedIndex` are almost the same thing. The only difference is that `selectedIndex` ends up being a string whereas `key` is a number. Not clear why you aren't just using `selectedIndex` for your `v-model` directly.
3. I don't know what `checkExist` does but `passSelect` feels like it should be a computed property from the code provided.
4. There shouldn't be any need to use `data-foo` to pass the option to the listener. You can get the relevant option directly from the data once you have the index. All of which assumes you actually need the index, otherwise you could just bind the `value` directly to the string option.